# DisposableObserver vs. (Regular) Observer

Tags: java, rx-java

From what I saw in the source code, the difference in terms of implementation is that the `DisposableObserver` implements the `Disposable` interface.

Inside `dispose`, it calls a helper function which disposes itself.

```
@Override
public final void dispose() {
    DisposableHelper.dispose(s);
}
```

But in practical terms, what is the difference between the two. Wouldn't be the regular Observable garbage collected as soon as it is not needed anymore?

What is the default use case for using `DisposableObserver` over `Observer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key difference is in the fact that the implementation can be changed at any time, and the change causes the disposing of the current disposable.

"A MutableDisposable is a disposable that can have its implementation changed at any time. The act of changing the disposable implementation causes the current disposable to dispose."

Answer (score 13):

It's mainly to avoid memory leaks, as it lets you cancel the subscription at any time. It can happen that an object that owns a subscription object reaches the end of its life cycle while the subscription is doing some heavy work that requires more time. In this case, the subscription will remain in memory, thus leaking the object that owns it. To avoid this, you can store the return value of the subscription (the disposable) and call `dispose` later at the end of the owner object's life cycle. Usually people end up adding each disposable to a `CompositeDisposable` (which is basically a bag of disposables) and then clearing them all together with `CompositeDisposable.clear()`, so that you don't have to keep track of each individual disposable.

Let's say you have a class called `ItemPublisher` that provides an infinite stream of events:

```
class ItemPublisher {
  // ...

  public Flowable<Item> getItemsStream() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Now, imagine that you have a class called `ItemHandler` that subscribes to that stream:

```
class ItemHandler {
  // ...

  public void observeItems() {

    itemPublisher.getItemsStream()
      .subscribe(
        // handle onNext events,
        // handle onError events
        // infinite stream, so we don't need to handle onComplete
      );
  }
}
```

So, your software is running, and everything's great. At a certain moment, your `ItemHandler` instance reaches the end of its lifetime. The instance is supposed to be destroyed. However, since we're dealing with the Observer pattern here, `ItemPublisher` retains an implicit reference to the `ItemHandler` instance, that was passed to it when you called the `subscribe` method. Since the stream is infinite, that reference will never be deleted, thus stoping the GC from cleaning up the `ItemHandler` instance, causing a memory leak. This does not happen with infinite streams only: if `ItemPublisher` has a longer life than `ItemHandler`, the same will happen.

That is why we have the `Disposable` interface. When you call `subscribe`, you can use the overloaded version of the method that returns a `Disposable`. When you don't need the subscription anymore, you can call `dispose()` on it. So, in our example:

```
class ItemHandler {
  private Disposable subscriber;  // this gets initialized somewhere

  // ...

  public void observeItems() {

    itemPublisher.getItemsStream()
      .subscribe(this.getSubscriber());
  }


  // later, when you know that this ItemHandler instance is not needed anymore
  public void wrapItUp() {
    // ...
    subscriber.dispose();
  }
}
```

As I mentioned before, you also have the `CompositeDisposable`, that comes in handy when you have a lot of subscriptions. By using it, you can gather all subscriptions into one place, and then get rid of them all at once. For instance:

```
class ItemHandler {
  private CompositeDisposable disposables;

  // ...

  public void observeItems() {

    disposables.add(itemPublisher.getItemsStream()
      .subscribe(
        // ...
      )
    );
  }


  public void observeSomethingElse() {
     disposables.add(somethingElse.getStreamOfSomethingElse()
      .subscribe(
        // ...
      )
    );
  }

  // later, when you know that this ItemHandler instance is not needed anymore
  public void wrapItUp() {
    // ...
    disposables.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not very clear for me. If you can rewrite in a cleaner fashion, I will assign you the bounty.

Comment: Thank you, it's a lot clearer now! Unfortunately, bounty has expired and I cannot assign you fully. But I think this will receive the upvotes that it deserves :).

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not in it for the bounty :P glad I could help!

Comment: This is a great answer about how , when and why to use disposable Interface.